A mistake in revised version
I have already submitted a revised version of my manuscript after considering the referees' reports. The paper is now in the final stage of reviewing by associated editor. I noticed that there is a mistake in the reference list and one reference has been repeated twice. What is the proper way in this stage that I can do?


I have already submitted a revised version of my manuscript after considering the referees' reports. The paper is now in the final stage of reviewing by associated editor.

You either fix it during the next round of revisions or during proofs. There is no need to contact anyone. The journal may even catch the mistakes, depending on what they are.
